# Global Chern-Simons forms and topological gauge theories

Tags: gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I am reading the classic Dijkgraaf and  Witten paper on topological gauge theories and something struck me that I didn't understand. For a trivial bundle $E$ on smooth 3-manifold $M$ with compact gauge group $G$ the Chern-Simons form is of course
$$S(A)=\frac{k}{8\pi^2}\int Tr (A\wedge dA + \frac{2}{3}A\wedge A\wedge A).$$

The confusing sentence is the following: "If  the bundle $E$ is not trivial, the formula for the action does not make sense, since a connection  on a non-trivial bundle  cannot be represented by a Lie algebra valued 1-form as in that formula." My concern is that this is wrong - of course we can represent a connection in a non-trivial bundle with a Lie-algebra valued 1-form! In fact, some texts define the connection in exactly that way (my trusty Choquet-Bruhat and DeWitt-Morette has that as one of their three equivalent definitions for a connection)- locally, a connection is represented as a linear map $\omega_p:T_p(E)\to \mathfrak{g}$.

So are we supposed to read the "as in that formula" to mean "globally"? Since of course, if the bundle is not trivial there isn't a *global* Lie-algebra valued 1-form that we can use for the Chern-Simons action. So that seems like a fine argument, but in QFT we are *always* writing down actions with sections of bundles (fields $\phi(x)$, say) which are not trivial - we just make sure that the action is invariant under the gauge transformations.

So, what is going on with that statement? Is it really saying we cannot represent a connection in such a way, or is it just stating the action is now local, and the rest of the paper is going to go on and tell me how to fix this with an element of $H^3(BG,\mathbb{R})$, etc.?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you say yourself, indeed every [connection on a bundle](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connection%20on%20a%20bundle) is *locally* given by a [Lie algebra valued 1-form](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid+of+Lie-algebra+valued+forms) and in general only locally.

Let's say this more in detail: for $X$ any manifold, a $G$-principal connection on it is (in "[Cech data](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C4%8Cech+cohomology)"):

1. a choice of [good open cover](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/good%20open%20cover) $\{U_i \to X\}$;
2. on each patch a 1-form $A_i \in \Omega^1(U_i)\otimes \mathfrak{g}$;
3. on each double intersection of patches a gauge transformation function $g_{i j} \in C^\infty(U_i \cap U_j, G)$

such that

1. on each double intersectin $U_i \cap U_j$ we have the equation $A_j = g_{i j}^{-1} A g_{i j} + g_{i j}^{-1} \mathbf{d} g_{i j}$
2. on each triple intersection $U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k$ we have the equation $g_{i j} g_{j k} = g_{i k}$.

Okay, now you would like to form a Chern-Simons 3-form... something out of this. What you immediately get from the above data is a bunch of local differential 3-forms, one on each patch: $CS(A_i) \in \Omega^3(U_i)$.

To make these 3-forms globally glue together to what is called a *[3-form connection](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/circle%20n-bundle%20with%20connection)* we need the evident data of [higher gauge transformation](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+gauge+field)

1. on each patch we have the local 3-form $CS(A_i)$;
2. on each double intersection there should be a 2-form $B_{i j} \in \Omega^2(U_i \cap U_j)$ which gauge transforms the respective CS-3-forms into each other, by $CS(A_j) = CS(A_i) + \mathbf{d} B_{i j}$;
3. on each triple intersection there should be a 1-form $\alpha_{i j k} \in \Omega^1(U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k)$ which exhibits a second-order gauge transformation ("[ghosts of ghosts](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ghost+field)"!) between the first order gauge trasformations, in that $B_{i j} + B_{j k} = B_{i  k} + \mathbf{d} \alpha_{ i j k}$
4. finally on each quadruple intersection there should be a smooth function $h_{i j k l} \in C^\infty(U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k \cap U_l, U(1))$ which gauge-of-gauge-of-gauge-transforms the gauge-of-gauge-transforms into each other, in that $\alpha_{i j k} + \alpha_{i k l} = \alpha_{j k l} + \alpha_{i j l} + h_{i j k l}^{-1}\mathbf{d}h_{i j k l}$.

That's the data that makes the local Chern-Simons 3-form into a globally well-defined 3-form field. (For instance the [supergravity C-field](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supergravity%20C-field) is of this form, with some further twists and bells and whistles added, as we have discussed [here](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/The+moduli+3-stack+of+the+C-field)).

In mathematical language one says that this kind of local gauge-of-gauge-of-gauge gluing data for global definition of higher form fields is a "degree-4 cocycle in [Cech-Deligne cohomology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Deligne%20cohomology)". This is *precisely* the right data needed to have a well-defined 3-dimensional [higher holonomy](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/holonomy) as is needed here for the definition, because the Chern-Simons action functional is nothing but the 3-dimensional higher holonomy of this 3-form connection.

If you can build it, that is. From the above it is not entirely obvious how to build the 3-form cocycle data $\{CS(A_i), B_{i j}, \alpha_{i j k}, h_{i j k}\}$ from the given gauge field data $\{A_i, g_{i j}\}$.

But this can be done. This is what [Cheeger-Simons differential characters](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cheeger-Simons%20differential%20character) were discovered for. An explicit construction that is very natural for the application to Chern-Simons theory we have given in

- Fiorenza, Schreiber, Stasheff, *Cech cocycles for differential characteristic classes*, Advances in Theoretical and Mathematical Phyiscs, Volume 16 Issue 1 (2012) ([arXiv:1011.4735](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4735), [web](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Cech+Cocycles+for+Differential+characteristic+Classes))

Based on this we give a detailed introduction to and discussion of Chern-Simons action functionals for globally non-trivial situations like above in

- Fiorenza, Sati, Schreiber, *A higher stacky perspective on Chern-Simons theory* ([arXiv:1301.2580](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2580), [web](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/A%20higher%20stacky%20perspective%20on%20Chern-Simons%20theory))

That article gives the local formulas that apply generally, discusses the simplifications that occur when the 3-manifold can be assumed to be bounding, discusses what happens if not, and then explores various other properties of globally defined Chern-Simons theory, such as how to couple Wilson lines to the above story. If you just look at the first part, I think you should find what you need.

---

edit: In the comments below came up the question why a similar discussion is not also needed when writing down the Yang-Mills action functional, whose Lagrangian is the 4-form $\langle F_A \wedge \star F_A \rangle$ (where $\star$ is the Hodge star of a given metric (gravity) and $\langle -,-\rangle$ is an invariant polynomial, the "Killing form" or trace), or similarly the topological Yang-Mills action functional, whose Lagrangian is the 4-form $\langle F_A \wedge  F_A \rangle$.

The reason is that these Lagrangians are built from *[curvatures](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/curvature) evaluated in an [invariant polynomial](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/invariant%20polynomial)*. The very invariance of these invariant polynomials under the adjoint action of the gauge group on its arguments ensures that if $\{U_i \to X\}$ is a good open cover of 4-dimensional space(-time) and if the gauge field is given by the Cech-cocycle data $\{A_i, g_{i j}\}$ with respect to these local patches, that then on double overlaps the two (topological or not) Yang-Mills Lagrangians  coming from two patches are already *equal*

$$
  \langle F_{A_i} \wedge F_{A_i}\rangle = \langle F_{A_j}\wedge F_{A_j}\rangle
  \,.
$$

Hence if we write $\nabla = \{A_i, g_{i j}\}$ for the gauge field connection abstractly and denote the (topological) Yang-Mills Lagrangian globally by $\langle F_\nabla \wedge F_\nabla\rangle$, then this is already a globally defined 4-form. Mathematically, this statement is what is at the core of [Chern-Weil theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Weil%20theory).

Notice that there is nevertheless an intricate relation to the story of the Chern-Simons functional. Namely the local [Chern-Simons form](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Simons%20form) $CS(A_i)$ has the special property (essentially by definition) that its differential is the topological Yang-Mills Lagrangian:

$$
  \mathbf{d}CS(A_i) = \langle F_{A_i} \wedge F_{A_i}\rangle
  \,.
$$

This means that with the Chern-Simons Lagrangian regarded as a [3-form connection](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/circle%20n-bundle%20with%20connection) then the topological Yang-Mills Lagrangian is its *curvature 4-form*.  Therefore the relation between the topological Yang-Mills Lagrangian 4-form and the Chern-Simons 3-form is precisely an analogue in higher gauge theory of the familiar relation two degrees down of how the electromagnetic potential 1-form -- which is not globally defined in general -- has a curvature 2-form that is globally well defined.

Mathematically this is why Chern-Simons functionals are called "[secondary invariants](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/secondary+characteristic+class)"

Indeed, this is a bit more than just an analogy: the Chern-Simons 3-form is precisely a doubly higher analog of the electromagnetic field as we pass from the point, via the string, to the [membrane](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/M2-brane).

I have some lecture notes with more along these lines at [nLab:twisted smooth cohomology in string theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/twisted%20smooth%20cohomology%20in%20string%20theory).

Comment: Ok a really great answer! The only thing it's missing is the emphasis on the difference between this and the "usual" thing - say Yang-Mills with action the integral of $F\wedge F$. It seems that we only consider double overlaps to determine these gauge transformations, so what is different about this case?

Comment: The difference with the Yang-Mills Lagrangian 4-form is that this happens to always be globally defined right away! This is becaus it is built only from the *curvatures*. The curvatures transform in the adjoint under gauge transformation, and the invariant form $\langle -,-\rangle$ that defines the (topological)YM-Lagrangian (the Killing form,the trace) $\langle F_{A_i} \wedge F_{A_i}\rangle$  is precisely such as to guarantee that on double overlaps we have an actual equality $\langle F_{A_i} \wedge F_{A_i}\rangle = \langle F_{A_j} \wedge F_{A_j}\rangle$. I'll add a comment to the above reply

Comment: Okay, I have added a second part to the reply above with some comments on how this relates to Yang-Mills.